# How to use alt key to duplicate nodes?

Tags: workflow, customization

I would like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate nodes in the shader editor, and really anywhere so that it is more consistent with my own workflow between programs that I use. <kbd>Alt</kbd> drag is used most frequently, and closer at hand.

This is easily done in the 3d viewport, simply replace <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>LMB</kbd> and objects will be duplicated this way. However, in the node editor, this doesn't seem to work at all. I end up aimlessly dragging nodes around doing nothing useful with them. Is there a a better way?

Here is how my prefs look for the settings that are of interest here:

[image]

This is what happens with the settings in action:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> is used by two other keymaps.

If you deselect them, it will work.

[image]